# Postgres collation with negated numerics

Tags: postgresql, collation

Is there a way to order by a varchar column numerically, so that the negated numbers go first:

`aaa-10bbb < aaa-2bbb < aaa2bbb`

I used the following collation

```
CREATE COLLATION custom_collation (provider = icu, locale = 'en-u-kn-true');
SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY a_field COLLATE custom_collation;
```

But the minus is not taken into account in this case.
Can I extend it somehow?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

lets define a new collation rule that includes the negation sign (-) as a separate character that should be treated as less than any numeric digit. and also set deterministic=true to ensure that the ordering is consistent across platforms, and co='<' to indicate that the less-than operator should be used for comparisons.

```
CREATE COLLATION custom_collation (
  provider = icu,
  locale = 'en-u-kn-true',
  deterministic = true,
  co = '<',
  collation_rules = '&0 < 1 < 2 < 3 < 4 < 5 < 6 < 7 < 8 < 9 < "-"'
) based on uca;

SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY a_field COLLATE custom_collation;
```

Comment: I don't think that syntax is valid for Postgres. According to [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createcollation.html) there is no `collation_rules` or `co` option. And `based on uca` is also invalid.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name True, but PostgreSQL v16 introduces `RULES` for custom collations, so it could be turned into an answer for v16 or better.